Adding a blank space after the end of an item in ConTeXt
How do you define an equivalent of an item in ConTeXt and then add specific vertical space after typing it?
In general how to apply a commmand after \item ,\sym etc?
For example i have this MWE:
\def\NewItem{\blank[big] \item}
\starttext
\startitemize
\item the first
\NewItem the second
\stopitemize
\stoptext

As you can see i can only apply blank command before \item because when i apply it after \item in defintion such as:
\def\NewItem{\item \blank[big]}

it first applies \blank and then types the text after the item.
I know that i can use \startitem \stopitem or using itemize different levels but is there a way to achieve this goal by using just \item?

Maybe \setupitemize[inbetween={\blank[big]}]?

@MaxChernoff It is good suggestion but i have several such command with different whitespace.
I want to use this to type several quote, which this extra space is for space between the quoter and its text and its translation

Hmm, what about \head (or maybe \sym) with \setupitemize[beforehead=..., afterhead=...]?

@MaxChernoff Intersting. could you describe this more? how to define setups after \sym or set symbol for \head?

We can use \head to add additional space before the “special” items. \head scans for its arguments weirdly though, so it's probably best to define a wrapper around it.
\setupheader[state=stop]
\setupindenting[yes, big]

\define\NormalItem{\item}
\tolerant\protected\def\SpecialItem#1\par{\head #1\par\doindentation}

\defineitemgroup[Items][
    indenting=next,
    inbetween={\blank[halfline]},
    beforehead={\blank[2*line]},
    afterhead={},
]

\starttext
    \startItems
        \NormalItem  This is the\dorecurse{6}{ first  normal  paragraph}.

                     This is the\dorecurse{6}{ second normal  paragraph}.

        \NormalItem  This is the\dorecurse{6}{ first  normal  paragraph}.

                     This is the\dorecurse{6}{ second normal  paragraph}.

        \SpecialItem This is the\dorecurse{6}{ first  special paragraph}.

                     This is the\dorecurse{6}{ second special paragraph}.

        \NormalItem  This is the\dorecurse{6}{ first  normal  paragraph}.

                     This is the\dorecurse{6}{ second normal  paragraph}.

        \SpecialItem This is the\dorecurse{6}{ first  special paragraph}.

                     This is the\dorecurse{6}{ second special paragraph}.

        \SpecialItem This is the\dorecurse{6}{ first  special paragraph}.

                     This is the\dorecurse{6}{ second special paragraph}.
    \stopItems
\stoptext


